# XSLT - First Instance of Empty Node edit

Tags: xslt-1.0

I am trying to edit the first instance of an empty node(Status) in the following xml :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='windows-1252'?>
<root>
  <row>
    <flowname>1</flowname>
    <path>#[payload]</path>
    <id>3</id>
    <setMessage>4</setMessage>
    <MockOne>5</MockOne>
    <MockTwo>6</MockTwo>
    <MockThree>7</MockThree>
    <Assert></Assert>
    <status>12</status>
  </row>
  <row>
    <flowname>2</flowname>
    <path>4</path>
    <id>5</id>
    <setMessage>6</setMessage>
    <MockOne>7</MockOne>
    <MockTwo>8</MockTwo>
    <MockThree></MockThree>
    <Assert></Assert>
    <status></status>
  </row>
  <row>
    <flowname>3</flowname>
    <path>5</path>
    <id>6</id>
    <setMessage>7</setMessage>
    <MockOne>8</MockOne>
    <MockTwo>9</MockTwo>
    <MockThree></MockThree>
    <Assert>3</Assert>
    <status></status>
  </row>
</root>
```

What I want to achieve is for the xslt to find the first instance of the  tag  which is empty and edit it to say 123. I tried using the following XSLT, but it seems to be replacing every Empty Status tag and I need it only to do the first instance. Kindly suggest on what has to be changed

The XSLT as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="row/status[1][not(text())][1]">
        <status>123</status>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output right now is as follows( Every empty Status tag is replaced instead of the first instance of an empty one)

```
<root>
  <row>
    <flowname>1</flowname>
    <path>#[payload]</path>
    <id>3</id>
    <setmessage>4</setmessage>
    <mockone>5</mockone>
    <mocktwo>6</mocktwo>
    <mockthree>7</mockthree>
    <assert></assert>
    <status>12</status>
  </row>
  <row>
    <flowname>2</flowname>
    <path>4</path>
    <id>5</id>
    <setmessage>6</setmessage>
    <mockone>7</mockone>
    <mocktwo>8</mocktwo>
    <mockthree></mockthree>
    <assert></assert>
    <status>123</status>
  </row>
  <row>
    <flowname>3</flowname>
    <path>5</path>
    <id>6</id>
    <setmessage>7</setmessage>
    <mockone>8</mockone>
    <mocktwo>9</mocktwo>
    <mockthree></mockthree>
    <assert>3</assert>
    <status>123</status>
  </row>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Xpath expression is saying to update all row/status which is empty.
You need to change like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="row[not(preceding-sibling::row[not(normalize-space(status))])]/status[1][not(text())][1]">
        <status>123</status>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```